# How can we direct the login / sign-on to use internal ADFS instead of External Proxy?

Tags: single-sign-on, adfs, box

We have the following setup for configuring SSO, where we are using ADFS as our IDP to connect to Box. Now when I choose SSO for login, it does not pass-through my Domain credentials, it directs me to my external ADFS sign in site. How can we direct the login / sign-on to use internal ADFS instead of External Proxy?

We are trying to do something where if accessed internally, we want to directly route to the internal ADFS server versus the external proxy. Maybe something similar to this?
http://community.office365.com/en-us/w/sso/358-using-smart-links-or-idp-initiated-authentication-with-office-365.aspx

Not sure if we need to do something like this:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee913565.aspx